# SignalR and AspNetHost.DependencyResolver

Tags: structuremap, signalr

I'm using SignalR in the application I am writing, but I'm confused by examples like the last example at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs in particular the use of AspNetHost.DependencyResolver

```
IConnectionManager connectionManager = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
dynamic clients = connectionManager.GetClients<MyHub>();
```

If I'm not mistaken this is a Dependency Injection tool?  Problem is I'm using StructureMap for everything else, and I'd rather not have two dependency Injection frameworks.

Is AspNetHost.DependencyResolver necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR has a bunch of dependencies/services that it needs to function, and it gets those through a DependencyResolver.

You can replace that resolver with your own (e.g StructureMap, Ninject etc.), but if you don't, SignalR will use it's default resolver.